# What is the difference between variadic template and ellipsis?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, overloading, language-lawyer

I know the title does no make much of a sense, but the code will explain my problem.

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T...) {std::cout << 'A';}

template<typename... Ts>
void foo(Ts...) {std::cout << 'B';}

int main(){  
   foo(1); 
   foo(1,2);
}
```

Try to guess the output of this program before reading the continuation:

So the output is `AB`

Can anyone explain why for 1 argument function the priority is given to ellipsis, and for 2 argument to variadic template?

Comment: Are you sure the first function template compiles?

Comment: @IgorR. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/67Dgk8

Comment: @Ayxan I'd say it's a weird gcc bug, but clang also compiles it... Thrilling.

Comment: @IgorR. why shouldn't it compile?

Comment: Why should it? You do not declare any template parameter pack, and then try and "unpack" something.  How do you read the first template?

Comment: Well, I *guess* the compiler reads it as `void foo(T, ...)`  - but I cannot find a paragraph in the standard that allows omiting the comma here.

Comment: Even more "fun" with `template<typename... Ts>
void foo(Ts......)`, read it as `foo(Ts..., ...)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 now it's only needed to explain why this overload is selected for the first call.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does overload resolution work with variadic functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876550/how-does-overload-resolution-work-with-variadic-functions)

Comment: @IgorR.: Whereas `(T...)` -> `(T, ...)` can go in comment (as not the question of OP), asked explanation of overload resolution should go in answer section, and that happens :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### What even is the first overload?

Per [[dcl.fct]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.decl#dcl.fct-4.sentence-8)

> Where syntactically correct and where “...” is not part of
>   an abstract-declarator, “, ...” is synonymous with “...”.

So this makes the first overload a variadic function (that also happens to be templated) that is equivalent to:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T, ...) {std::cout << 'A';}
```

(N.B. The [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic) page contains an example with similar elision of the comma between the first argument and the variadic arguments.)

#### Why do we see that specific output?

The compiler prefers the *other overload* when you pass two arguments because, during overload resolution, an ellipsis conversion sequence is always ranked dead last when ranking viable overloads. ([[over.ics.rank]](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#over.ics.rank-2))

The compiler prefers this first overload when a single argument is passed because simply, the ellipsis is not matched (because there is nothing to match). This prevents the function from being considered as an ellipsis conversion sequence. Normal function template ranking then happens and it is determined that this function is more specialized than the variadic one ([[temp.deduct.partial]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.partial#11))

Comment: Just note that you can reference a particular sentence, which might be more convenient here: [dcl.fct/4/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.decl#dcl.fct-4.sentence-8).

Comment: @DanielLangr: Thanks I did not know that

Comment: Yes, it's a variadic function, but the OP already knew that. He's asking why the second call uses the variadic function template instead of the C-style variadic function.

Comment: @Sebastian Redl  Variadic function is always the worst match. So the question probably is why the first call uses it.

Comment: It does compile without the first function https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bhsmzb

Comment: @Ayxan: Both functions are viable for the 2 calls. We have then to follow (complex) rule of overload resolution to find the best match.

Comment: @IgorR.: Variadic is not the worst match, but a tie-breaker.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: Okay, I think I've added an acceptable explanation for the overload resolution.

Answer (score 5):

Following [overload_resolution#Best_viable_function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Best_viable_function)

- For `f(1)`,

  We go though 5)

  > or, if not that, F1 and F2 are both template specializations and F1 is more specialized according to the partial ordering rules for template specializations

  And from [Function_template_overloading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading)

  > After considering every P and A in both directions, if, for each type that was considered,
  >   [..]
  >
  > In case of a tie, if one function template has a trailing parameter pack and the other does not, the one with the omitted parameter is considered to be more specialized than the one with the empty parameter pack.

  So ellipsis function `template<typename T> void foo(T,...)` is considered more specialized than variadic `template<typename ...Ts> void foo(Ts...)`.
- for `f(1, 2)`

  Reading [Ranking_of_implicit_conversion_sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Ranking_of_implicit_conversion_sequences)

  In variadic version we have exact match, whereas ellipsis has ellipsis conversion sequence

  So variadic is better match.

Comment: While this does explain the overload resolution (`+1`), I think for the sake of completeness, you should also mention why the first function is a C style variadic function. OP seems to not be aware of that.

Comment: @Ayxan: I don't see any confusion from OP. There was from some commentators though

Comment: I may be wrong, but `foo(T...)` instead `foo(T, ...)` in a template context seems like a confusion to me.

Comment: @Ayxan: I would say obfuscation instead of confusion.

Comment: What kind of person obfuscates the code they need help with in some other way, and then doesn't mention it? The point is to make it harder for others to help you? Or maybe I need some more coffee.

Comment: OP is maybe used to use ellipsis that way. As with operator precedence, some are considered known and then adding parenthesis might be considered redundant and just add verbosity (`3 + (4 * 5)`, `(a + b) < c`), for other omitting "extra" parenthesis is unsecure and obfuscation (`a || b1 && b2`). Not always easy to know what is confusing for others (especially when we are already in the context).