# Issue with overloaded variadic function in c++

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-functions

```
void fun(int a, ....)
{
  cout<< "variadic function"<<endl;
}
void fun(int a, int b)
{
  cout<< "function"<<endl;
}
int main()
{ 
  fun(1,2);
}
```

output : function

I have overloaded the variadic function. How do I make sure it should link to the variadic function?

Comment: Don't provide an overload that's a better match if you don't want it.

Comment: This should be an answer.

Comment: My advice is to never use variadic functions in C++. There's no type-checking of the arguments, and the promotion of some arguments might sometimes lead to unexpected values. Use template parameter packs instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does overload resolution work with variadic functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876550/how-does-overload-resolution-work-with-variadic-functions)

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that according to the standard ([see here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments)):

> Because variadic parameters have the lowest rank for the purpose of
> overload resolution, they are commonly used as the catch-all fallbacks
> in SFINAE.

functions with variadic parameters always have the lowest priority for overload resolution. As a result, in your case, the second overload, (i.e. `fun(int a, int b)`) will be called. But as already advised by other users in the comments, try to never use functions with variadic parameters in C++ due to the lack of type checking of the arguments.